# Replace the dot at the end of a string in R

Tags: r, regex

Here is a string.

```
"DEL.Xp22.11..ZFX."
```

I want to replace the `..` with a space and a left parenthesis  `(` and the last `.` with a right parenthesis `)`.

```
"DEL.Xp22.11 (ZFX)"
```

I tried the following to replace the double dots while I dont know how to replace the last dot.

```
gsub("..", ' (', "DEL.Xp22.11..ZFX.", fixed = T)

[1] "DEL.Xp22.11 (ZFX."
```

Comment: Is it always the last character or always the last dot?

Comment: `gsub('\\.\\.(.*)\\.$', ' (\\1)', 'DEL.Xp22.11..ZFX.')`

Comment: @rawr Hi. What does (\\1) mean?

Comment: @LinCaijin it is a reference to the first capture group

Comment: Can more than one single period follow the double-period? For example, could the string be `"DEL..Xp22.11ZFX."` and you wish it to become `"DEL (Xp22.11ZFX)"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :

```
x <- "DEL.Xp22.11..ZFX."
x <- gsub("..", ' (', x, fixed = T)
x <- gsub("\\.$", ')', x)
```

Here I use the regex anchor '$' to signify the end of the word. And '\' to escape the '.' that is a regex special character.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the following regex-based solution:

```r
sub("\\.{2}([^.]+)\\.$", "(\\1)", x)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VY8h2q/1). *Details*:

- `\.{2}` - two dots
- `([^.]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this value from the replacement pattern): one or more chars other than a `.` char
- `\.` - a single dot
- `$` - end of string.

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/Yopu2U):

```r
x <- "DEL.Xp22.11..ZFX."
sub("\\.{2}([^.]+)\\.$", "(\\1)", x)
# => [1] "DEL.Xp22.11(ZFX)"
```